# Back-of-the-envelope calculation of electron anomalous magnetic moment

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-moment

I wonder if there is an intuitive way to obtain the $\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}$ correction to electron's $\frac12 (g-2)$ just like how Bethe estimated the Lamb shift?

Here is an attempt by Drell & Pagels (dispersion relation)
[Link](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.140.B397)

Comment: relevant http://books.google.com/books?id=wABQhIVmQn8C&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22we+have+been+computing+terms+like+a+blind+man%22&source=bl&ots=9MyYfAmNEv&sig=fJ2I0CumFEwiN0FyZNyxYg7KVvE&hl=en&ei=q3vATumBB8OC2AXWzp2HBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22we%20have%20been%20computing%20terms%20like%20a%20blind%20man%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

T. Welton gave an estimation in 1948. It was of good order of magnitude but of the opposite sign, apparently, because his estimations were non-relativistic and did not take into account virtual pairs. https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4Db4rFq72mLOTE4ZTQ0NzUtMzZmNy00ZDU1LTgwNDQtMjU4NDUwMDAyMDg0

Comment: about the nonrelativistic concern: Drell&Pagels also included NR estimate and they got the sign correct. Another possibility is that somehow the magnetic correction reduces the electron mass.